# MS Access Query Timeout When inserting row in SQL Backend

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, locks

My users are receiving the query timeout error when they try to insert data to SQL server 2008 through an Access 2010 form. The error msg specifically occurs when users move off the record having keyed in all data fields.

When I look into Activity Monitor in SQL Server I can see many blocked SPIDs throughout the day but they do soon clear up. I don't know why this happens and the only solution seems to be restarting the SSMS Services.  I don't think its a memory issue as the server has got 8GB which is plenty.  The SQL DB is only 400 MB, but there are many transactions taking place across 2 sites.

I do notice that the SSMS memory consumption is around 3.5GB at the time of this error.  After the restart this goes down of course.

Where do I start looking? is it network related or is it a blocked process due to local VBA code which could be moved to SQL Server? or is it cache related?

I'm no DBA so not sure of how to go about the search.
Thanks

Comment: Has your table a primary key with an index and a timestamp field ?